# how to get data from database using Sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

how can i Fix this problem and why this words getting red MoveToNext why its get red and res is also get red colour

public void viewAll() {

```
    ViewBtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                   Cursor res = dbHelper.getAllData();
                   if (res.getCount() == 0);
                   showMessage("Error","No Appointments");

                   return;
                }

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while (res.moveToNext()) {
                    buffer.append("CustomerID :" + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Name :" + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Date :" + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Time :" + res.getString(3) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Gender :" + res.getString(3) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Service :" + res.getString(3) + "\n");
                }

                showMessage("Appointments",buffer.toString());
            }
    );
}
public void showMessage(String title,String Message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPokt.png)

Comment: Isn't `res` local to `onClick()` but being used outside of that scope in your code?

Answer (score 0):

`dbHelper` is empty and you have not set it as the primary activity.
Just replace

```
DBHelper mdbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
```

to

```
dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
```

Always use the `dbHelper` object and remove `mdbHelper`